# How to display a value based on a different value in a different table in an MS Access form?

Tags: ms-access

I am a complete beginner.  I am working on an invoicing project.  Essentially, I have a table (tblCustomers) that stores a value (SalesType).  The SalesType can be one of these values: Cash Sale or Trade Sale.

In another table (tblProducts), I have a list of products and their price.  The prices are either a cash price or trade price.  ProductType,CashPrice & TradePrice.

At the moment, on my invoice form (frmInvoice), I have 3 items.  A combo box where user can select the product, a text box that displays the Cash Price and another text box that displays the Trade Price.

What I am looking for is a way for Access to check the SalesType from tblCustomer for a given customer and depending on what is listed there, i.e. either cash sale or trade sale, for a text box to display the correct price.

Comment: Use Dlookup() function.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article to use `DLookup()` function. It will solve your problem.

[DLookup Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937)

Comment: Tips for posting answers: (a) summarise the link you have offered in the answer itself, if only to save it from deletion by the Review Queue; (b) refrain from meta-commentary inviting a discussion about the topic at hand. Some discussion is inevitable to get to an answer, but Stack Overflow is not a discussion platform, and answers ought to reflect that.